# How to get Android Internal App Sharing key SHA1 to enable Google APIs?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

Google APIs are not working with Internal App Sharing, this might be due to the Google Play App re-signing which is mentioned in [Share app bundles and APKs internally](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9303479)

How can I get Internal App Sharing key SHA1 to add on Google API console?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find the Internal App signing key under **Development Tools -> Internal app sharing -> App Certificates** on Google Play Console after submitting your App.

[image: Android Internal test certificate's fingerprints]

Comment: OK great, so once you have this key what do you do with it to get, say, Google Maps for Android to work within an app shared via Internal App Sharing?!

Comment: @RobP Yes, you must use this fingerprint for GoogleMap. Firebase etc., only when you are using Internal App sharing.

Comment: Please don't downvote unless you tested, this is the correct answer.

Comment: The answer is correct as far as it goes, but insufficient. After finding this fingerprint, there is a tricky set of steps in the API console to add that fingerprint to the various APIs like Google Maps for Android. I figured it out, but it's very much non-obvious and part of the question being asked. Add that to the answer and I would certainly remove the downvote!

Comment: @RobP Can you add the things you figured out in a separate answer then?

Comment: @RobP can you please guide with tricky steps. I am facing issue with google map while sharing app through internal app sharing. Map not shown while sharing app bundle through internal app sharing.

Comment: @KetanMehta see the Answer and find the SHA1 and add SHA1 under Google Cloud's Map APIs.

Comment: @ChathuraWijesinghe Thanks man. Did same steps and now able to see MAP in internal app sharing build.

Answer (score 0):

> You can get key by pragmatically by doing this surround with try catch

```
private void printKeyhas()
{
  PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName()),PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURE);

for(Signature signature.info.signature)
{
   MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstanse("SHA");
   md.update(signature.toByteArray());
  log.d("KEY_HASH",Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),Base64.DEFAULT));
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find App Certificates on Google Play Console , Release Management -> App Releases -> Manage Internal app sharing -> App Certificates. 
[image]
Copy SHA-1 certificate fingerprint that is used to add in Google Cloud Platform with your associated API Keys like Map Key, Device Verification key.

You can easily generate **Keyhash(ssh)** through SHA-1 fingerprint by following command of OpenSSL

> echo < Genrated SHA1 Fingerprint> | xxd -r -p | openssl base64

Keyhash is used on facebook dev console

Answer (score -2):

Type this in your console or command prompt :

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\Hp\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Comment: the above command is to get the Android debug key SHA1 NOT the Internal App Sharing key SHA1